# hadoop single node setup

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to do a single  node setup for hadoop as given on following link http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/single_node_setup.html
i have followed all the steps till defining JAVA_HOME but the command "$ bin/hadoop" is not working for me.there is no file or folder related to hadoop in my bin folder.what does this command do and why its not working for me??

Comment: You can go through this link.
http://lets-do-something-big.blogspot.in/2014/01/hbase-installation-on-ubuntu-lubuntu.html
It gives a very good idea on installation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that means execute the command './bin/hadoop' from the hadoop home directory.  That is, the hadoop command is in the bin sub-directory underneath the hadoop install directory.

Comment: thanks paul ...i didnt know i had to run it from hadoop home directory

Comment: @shshnk -- if that solved the problem, can you please mark the question as answered?  I'm fairly new to StackOverflow, but I think the community encourages that.  If you are still stuck, let me know that as well and I'll dig further.  Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 0):

```
The check_basic_env.sh Script

#! /bin/sh
# This block is trying to do the basics of checking to see if
# the HADOOP_HOME and the JAVA_HOME variables have been set correctly
# and if they are not been set, suggest a setting in line with the earlier examples
#  The script actually tests for:
#  the presence of the java binary and the hadoop script,
#  and verifies that the expected versions are present
#  that the version of java and hadoop is as expected (warning if not)
#  that the version of java and hadoop referred to by the
#  JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_HOME environment variables are default version to run.
#
#
#  The 'if [' construct you see is a shortcut for 'if test' ....
#  the -z tests for a zero length string
#  the -d tests for a directory
#  the -x tests for the execute bit
#  -eq tests numbers
#  = tests strings
#  man test will describe all of the options
# The '1>&2' construct directs the standard output of the
# command to the standard error stream.
if [ -z "$HADOOP_HOME" ]; then
     echo "The HADOOP_HOME environment variable is not set" 1>&2
     if [ -d ~/src/hadoop-0.19.0 ]; then
         echo "Try export HADOOP_HOME=~/src/hadoop-0.19.0" 1>&2
     fi
     exit 1;
fi
# This block is trying to do the basics of checking to see if
# the JAVA_HOME variable has been set
# and if it hasn't been set, suggest a setting in line with the earlier examples
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
     echo "The JAVA HOME environment variable is not set" 1>&2
     if [ -d /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_07 ]; then
         echo "Try export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_07" 1>&2
     fi
     exit 1
fi


# We are now going to see if a java program and hadoop programs
# are in the path, and if they are the ones we are expecting.
# The which command returns the full path to the first instance
# of the program in the PATH environment variable
#
JAVA_BIN=`which java`
HADOOP_BIN=`which hadoop`
# Check for the presence of java in the path and suggest an
# appropriate path setting if java is not found
if [ -z "${JAVA_BIN}" ]; then
    echo "The java binary was not found using your PATH settings" 1>&2
    if [ -x ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ]; then
        echo 'Try export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin' 1>&2
    fi
    exit 1
fi
# Check for the presence of hadoop in the path and suggest an
# appropriate path setting if java is not found
if [ -z "${HADOOP_BIN}" ]; then
    echo "The hadoop binary was not found using your PATH settings" 1>&2
    if [ -x ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop ]; then
        echo 'Try export PATH=${HADOOP_HOME}/bin:${PATH}' 1>&2
    fi
    exit 1
fi
# Double check that the version of java installed in ${JAVA_HOME}
# is the one stated in the examples.
# If you have installed a different version your results may vary.
#
if ! ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -version 2>&1 | grep -q 1.6.0_07; then
    (echo –n "Your JAVA_HOME version of java is not the"
     echo –n " 1.6.0_07 version, your results may vary from"
     echo " the book examples.") 1>&2
fi
# Double check that the java in the PATH is the expected version.
if ! java -version 2>&1 | grep -q 1.6.0_07; then
    (echo –n "Your default java version is not the 1.6.0_07 "
     echo –n "version, your results may vary from the book"
     echo " examples.") 1>&2
fi

   # Try to get the location of the hadoop core jar file
   # This is used to verify the version of hadoop installed
   HADOOP_JAR=`ls -1 ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-0.19.0-core.jar`
   HADOOP_ALT_JAR=`ls -1 ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-*-core.jar`
   # If a hadoop jar was not found, either the installation
   # was incorrect or a different version installed
   if [ -z "${HADOOP_JAR}" -a -z "${HADOOP_ALT_JAR}" ]; then
        (echo –n "Your HADOOP_HOME does not provide a hadoop"
         echo –n " core jar. Your installation probably needs"
         echo –n " to be redone or the HADOOP_HOME environment"
         echo variable needs to be correctly set.") 1>&2
        exit 1
   fi
   if [ -z "${HADOOP_JAR}" -a ! -z "${HADOOP_ALT_JAR}" ]; then
        (echo –n "Your hadoop version appears to be different"
         echo –n " than the 0.19.0 version, your results may vary"
         echo " from the book examples.") 1>&2
   fi
   if [ `pwd` != ${HADOOP_HOME} ]; then
        (echo –n 'Please change your working directory to"
         echo –n " ${HADOOP_HOME}. cd ${HADOOP_HOME} <Enter>") 1>&2
        exit 1
   fi
   echo  "You are good to go"
   echo  –n "your JAVA_HOME is set to ${JAVA_HOME} which "
   echo  "appears to exist and be the right version for the examples."
   echo  –n "your HADOOP_HOME is set to ${HADOOP_HOME} which "
   echo  "appears to exist and be the right version for the examples."
   echo  "your java program is the one in ${JAVA_HOME}"
   echo  "your hadoop program is the one in ${HADOOP_HOME}"
   echo  –n "The shell current working directory is ${HADOOP_HOME} "
   echo  "as the examples require."
   if [ "${JAVA_BIN}" = "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" ]; then
        echo "Your PATH appears to have the JAVA_HOME java program as the default java."
   else
        echo –n "Your PATH does not appear to provide the JAVA_HOME"
        echo " java program as the default java."
   fi


if [ "${HADOOP_BIN}" = "${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop" ]; then
     echo –n "Your PATH appears to have the HADOOP_HOME"
     echo " hadoop program as the default hadoop."
else
     echo –n "Your PATH does not appear to provide the the HADOOP_HOME "
     echo "hadoop program as the default hadoop program."
fi
exit 0
```

This script will help you to check all your env variables and configs.
Try this bash script, by storing it hadoop root directory.
Run it by simply writing ./check_basic_env.sh .

Answer (score 0):

The hadoop script and other useful scripts are in {hadoop_install_directory}/bin directory. Of course, feel free to add this directory to $PATH or create symbol link from /usr/bin or $HOME/bin.